# jsDOM cannot change background color by class or tag

Tags: javascript, dom, tampermonkey

I am trying to change the background Color of an element on another website with tamper monkey. However every time I try it sends the error: cannot change background-color of undefined.

I have tried using getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName after which I use the style property then backgroundColor of course.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("rdw");
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";

})();
```

I would like to use getElementsByClassId because I feel in this scenario its more precise.

As stated I get the error cannot change background color of undefined.

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection and not a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the return value of getElementsByClassName is

> An HTMLCollection providing a live-updating list of every element
>   which is a member of every class in names.

so, if you have only one element with that class, you should pick the first one :

```
x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

otherwise you'll have to loop through the elements :

```
[...x].forEach(el => el.style.backgroundColor = "red");
```

Comment: HTMLCollection doesn't have a .forEach() though.